# Bigquery autoconverting fields in data

Tags: json, google-bigquery

**Background**

In Bigquery autodetect,i have following json data being loaded to BQ table.

"a":"","b":"q"

"a":"","b":"q1"

"a":"1","b":"w2"

Now,when this json is uploaded,BQ throws error cannot convert field "a" to integer.

**Thoughts**

I guess BQ,after reading two rows,BQ infers field "a" as string and then later when "a":"1" comes ,BQ tries to convert it to integer(But why?).

So,to investigate more,i modified the json as follows.

"a":"f","b":"q"

"a":"v","b":"q1"

"a":"1","b":"w2"

Now,when i use this json,no errors,data is smoothly loaded to table.

I don't see as to why in this scenario,if BQ infers field "a" as string,how come it throws no error (why does it not try to convert "a":"1" to integer)?

**Query**

What i assume is,BQ infers a field to a particular type ,only when it sees data in the field("a":"1" or "a":"f"),but what i don't get is why is BQ trying to automatically converting ("a":"1") to integer when it is of type string.

This autoconversion could create issues.

Please let me know,if my assumptions are correct and what could be done to avoid such errors because realtime data isnot in my control,i can only control my code(using autodetect).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug with autodetect. We are working on a fix.

Comment: what could be the estimated time for its fix?

Comment: It usually takes some time for the fix to propagate through all the different testing systems and environments before it is cleared for production - so conservative estimate is few weeks.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky,could you pls. update whether this bug is fixed and is autodetect feature ok to be used with load tables?

Comment: The fix should be live in production now.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky, can you please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317427/bigquery-loadjob-of-a-json-forcing-a-field-to-be-string-in-the-schema-auto-det