# "Invalid schema update" error when loading data using autodetect

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table with one single field named "version", which is a string. When I try to load data into the table using autodetect with values like `"1.1"` or `"1"`, the autodetect feature infers these values as float or integer type respectively.

**data1.json** example:

```
{ "version": "1.11.0" }
```

`bq load` output:

`$ bq load --autodetect --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON temp_test.temp_table ./data1.json
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_ZZZ ... (1s) Current status: DONE`

**data2.json** example:

```
{ "version": "1.11" }
```

`bq load` output:

`$ bq load --autodetect --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON temp_test.temp_table ./data2.json
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_ZZZ ... (0s) Current status: DONE

BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'YYY:bqjob_ZZZ': Invalid schema update. Field version has changed type from STRING to FLOAT`

**data3.json** example:

```
{ "version": "1" }
```

`bq load` output:

`$ bq load --autodetect --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON temp_test.temp_table ./data3.json
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_ZZZ ... (0s) Current status: DONE

BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'YYY:bqjob_ZZZ': Invalid schema update. Field version has changed type from STRING to INTEGER`

The scenario where this problem doesn't happen is when you have, in the same file, another JSON where the value is inferred correctly as string (as seen in [Bigquery autoconverting fields in data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611477/bigquery-autoconverting-fields-in-data) question):

```
{ "version": "1.12" }
{ "version": "1.12.0" }
```

In the question listed above, there's an answer stating that a fix was pushed to production, but it looks like the bug is back again. Is there a way/workaround to prevent this?

Comment: It looks to me BigQuery is inferring the types correctly? data1.json is a string, data2.json is a float, and data3.json is a integer. If the value for a column is "1.12", then the most accurate type that describes the column is float; if the value for a column can be "1.12" or "1.12.0", then the type of the column can only be string. It'll be nice if BigQuery can use the type of the column in the table to help the auto-detect, but I think it's more like a feature request than a bug.

Comment: @HuaZhang I don't agree. If the value is enclosed by double quotes, it should be considered a string. In a standard JSON file, booleans, integers and floats don't have double quotes.

Comment: I see your point. BigQuery has been able to parse strings like "1.12" as double for a long time though, so auto-detect strings like "1.12" as double is by design. Many customers depend on this design, so it's unlikely to change.

Comment: @HuaZhang gotcha. A parameter to disable this behavior for existing fields would be great. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @HuaZhang, could you post a comment with the information you provided in the comments? It will help the Community to better understand BigQuery ;)

Comment: @enlelin I guess you meant post it as an answer :)

Comment: Looks like BigQuery is treating JSON as if it was CSV. Absolutely no need to interpret strings as numbers in JSON and very counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the confusing part here is whether "1.12" should be detected as string or float. BigQuery chose to detect as float. Before autodetect is introduced in BigQuery, BigQuery allows users to load float values in string format. This is very common in CSV/JSON format. So when autodetect is introduced, it kept this behavior. Autodetect will scan up to 100 rows to detect the type. If for all 100 rows, the data is like "1.12", then very likely this field is a float value. If one of the row has value "1.12.0", then BigQuery will detect the type is string, as you have observed.

Comment: If the user defined column as STRING and you are uploading from CSV values which are numbers. Why it fails? "Invalid schema update. Field item_code has changed type from STRING to INTEGER (error code: invalid)"  - Why can't it put the integer in the string column?! I don't want to change the filed type.

Comment: Are you using schema auto-detection or specified the schema of the csv file? If you specify the column as INTEGER, or let auto-detection detects it as INTEGER, BigQuery will think that the table has the column as STRING, while the data has it as INTEGER, and fail. If you specify the column as STRING, the parsing logic knows how to parse INTEGER as STRING. Then for BigQuery, both the table and the data has the column as STRING, so it's fine too.

Comment: No auto detection. Schema is set. it has been working for 4 months. One of the columns is STRING but the column in the csv happened to be integer (this csv had only 20 rows usualy we have 80000+) so it happened that all of the values for this column are numbers. While uploading it fails. If I change one value to "gg" it works - because then it understand that the column is string.  I don't understand it.

Comment: The fact that "gg" makes it working seems to indicate auto detect is invoked. "gg" forced it to detect the column as STRING. But if you set the column as STRING in the schema, then auto detect shouldn't be invoked. The following command works for me: bq load my_dataset.csv_test ~/Downloads/test.csv value:STRING. test.csv has one integer 1. The table has a single column of type STRING. I also specified the type to be STRING in the load command.

Comment: *"This is very common in CSV/JSON format."*, yes for CSV, absolutely not for JSON. In JSON, strings are enclosed with quotes ALWAYS, numbers are enclosed with quotes NEVER. There is zero ambiguity (dates are another matter unfortunately).