# bigquery loadJob of a json - forcing a field to be String in the schema auto-detect

Tags: google-bigquery

if in the beginning the json contains

> "label": "foo"

and later it is

> "label": "123"

bigquery returns

```
Invalid schema update. Field label has changed type from STRING to INTEGER
```

although it is "123" and not 123.

file is being loaded with

> autodetect: true

is there a way to force **bigquery** to make any field as string when it applies its auto-detect, or the only way is using csv instead ?

Answer (score 3):

The [auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#auto-detect) is based on the best effort to recognize the data type by scanning up to 100 rows of data to use as a representative sample. There is no way to give insight about which kind of type it is. You may consider to specify manually the schema for your use case.

**UDATE:**

I have tested to load a file with only `{"label" : "123"}` and it is recognized as `INTEGER`. Therefore, the auto detection recognizes `"123"` as `INGETER` no matter if there are quotes or not. For your case, you may consider to [export the schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source) from the existent table as explained in the documentation:

> Note: You can view the schema of an existing table in JSON format by
>   entering the following command: bq show --format=prettyjson
>   [DATASET].[TABLE].

and use it for further dynamic loads

Comment: thank you. Yes, the issue is that each json is dynamic and might contain new elements, that's the reason for the auto-detect config. Once bigquery already determined the type of an element from the 'history' as a string, why it can't treat a new value as a string anymore, even though it looks like a integer. Moreover, the value contains quotes :(

Comment: @ShaharT Auto detection interprets `"123"` as `INTEGER` and you should specify schema for JSON file when loading it to BigQuery. Notice that you can export schema from an existent table. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: the issue is that in the first value, bigquery loaded it as string, and in the next json load, I expect bigquery to force it to be string (as it already auto-detected it before)

Comment: I think each load job is treated independently so the auto-detect will apply again for each load. Therefore, if some load has only numbers in the 100 rows sample to determinate the schema, it will detect the field as `INTEGER` (no matter if it was detected as `STRING` in the previous load). The auto detection is done by best effort and you may specify the schema manually in your case.